# Xdocument throws error while XMLdocument loads sucessfully the same xml string

Tags: c#, xml

The existing Project  loads the XMLDocument from a string transactionXML which is like

```
 \n\t<Transaction>
  \n\t\t<TransactionId>6109</TransactionId>
  n\t\t<TransactionType>ClaimsCorrespondenceEvent
 </TransactionType>\n\t\t<TransactionStatus>
```

The below code loads xml sucessfully:

```
   document.LoadXml(transactionXML);
```

but the below code fails and gives exception of invalid character referring to the \n\t etc.

```
     XDocument.Load(transactionXML);
```

I need to use XDocument as I am using the method Descendants of XDocument which is not available in XMLDocument.

Please is there a way to load the above string by using XDocument. Alternatively how do I use XMLdocument to get all the nodes along with the child with node name "Transaction"

The example XML would be :

```
<Transactions>
  <Transaction>
   <Version> 1 </Version>
   <Id> 2 </Id>
  </Transaction>
  <Transaction>
     <Version> 2 </Version>
     <Id> 3 </Id>
    </Transaction>
   <Transaction>
     <Version> 3 </Version>
     <Id> 4 </Id>
   </Transaction>
</Transactions>
```

and I want separate XML for the node Transaction along with its child elements like :

Ist XML set

```
    <Transaction>
     <Version> 1 </Version>
     <Id> 2 </Id>
    </Transaction>
```

2nd XMl set

```
  <Transaction>
     <Version> 2 </Version>
     <Id> 3 </Id>
    </Transaction>
```

3rd XMl set

```
   <Transaction>
     <Version> 3 </Version>
     <Id> 4 </Id>
   </Transaction>
```

Please if some one could let me know how to go about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `XDcoument`, to load xml from a string, you need to use `Parse` not `Load`; Load accepts a file path and not an xml string, try:

```
var xml = XDocument.Parse(transactionXML);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument(v=vs.110).aspx